# Guess a formula for $a_n$ and proof it by induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Series $a_1, a_2,a_3…$ is defined for all  $n≥1 ,a_1= 1$ and after that $a_{n+1} =  a_n/(2+a_n )$,   for n≥1.
Guess a formula for $a_n$ and proof it by induction. 
I would need help with this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I calculated the first $6$ terms:
$$a_1 = 1,\ a_2 = \frac{1}{3},\ a_3 = \frac{1}{7},\ a_4 = \frac{1}{15},\ a_5 = \frac{1}{31},\ a_6 = \frac{1}{63}$$
From this, we can have a pretty good guess that
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2^n-1}$$
**Proof by induction:**

**I.** It works for $n=1$:
$$a_1 = \frac{1}{2^1-1} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$
**II.** Assume that
$$\forall k \in \{1,\dots,n\}:\ \ a_k = \frac{1}{2^k-1}$$
**III.** Prove for $k+1:$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{a_k}{2+a_k} = \frac{\frac{1}{2^k-1}}{2+\frac{1}{2^k-1}}=\frac{1}{2^k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{2^{k+1}-2+1}{2^{k}-1}}=\frac{1}{2^k-1}\cdot\frac{2^{k}-1}{2^{k+1}-1} = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}-1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider that
$$
\frac{a_n}{2+a_n}=\frac{1}{\dfrac{2}{a_n}+1}
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{2}{a_n}+1
$$

Can you make a guess for $b_n$ defined by $b_1=1$ and $b_{n+1}=2b_n+1$?

Comment: You could just turn over both sides to get this.

Comment: @ChristianF The first step shows the idea: we can make $a_n$ to appear just once in the expression.

Comment: Yes, I'l give you +1